# Ansible Upgrade along with playbooks

Tags: ansible

Is there any way to upgrade ansible version along with the playbooks which are written in older version of ansible. Any kind of script which would read all the modules in the playbooks and recommend / update them to new versions

Comment: This question seems to be better suited for http://serverfault.com/, the Stack Exchange site dedicated to server administration. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Hi Sunny, welcome to SO! Please try and make your question specific, otherwise it runs the risk of being closed for being too broad. For example, perhaps pick a specific "playbook for older ansible" and ask how it might be upgraded, since none of us know what you consider such a thing to be. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Although it won't upgrade your playbooks for you (you have to do that yourself), you could use [Ansible Lint](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint). Run it over your existing playbooks and address the issues that it finds. If you want to be even more sure, run the playbooks in check mode `ansible-playbook -C ...` to see if any module names or parameters need updating.